# sending logs to multiple Azure Log analytics workspaces

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I have a scenario at my work where i need to send logs from multiple resources on azure to single log analytics workspace for compliance purpose and then ingest the same logs to Azure Sentinel workspace for SIEM services, i however cannot enable Azure Sentinel on the first workspace, any leads or solutions please.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you give more information on the 'Cannot enable Azure Sentinel'? What steps are being taken / Any errors.

Comment: @blockingHD let me be more clear, we have 2 workspaces(workspace1&2), i need logs of all the resources in a subscription to be ingested to both the workspace. one is used for compliance purpose with a longer retention period and another for Sentinel with a shorter retention, i am looking for any leads on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think your best option is to put everything into one log analytics workspace with the longer retention period but lets say that is not at all possible.

I can see 2 options here:
The easiest is probably to set up 2 [diagnostic settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings) on each resource which points to the separate log analytics work spaces.

A much harder option would be to use [continuous export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export) into Azure Storage (which could be all you need to do) or event hub and then process this back into log analytics with an Azure function.

Last comments would be that your going to be paying for the data ingest twice no matter what is done here which will at least double your costs for the lower retention time.